# Optimize regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a requirement that a password must contain one upper case, lower case, digit and special character. Password length should be 6 to 10 characters. Based on it i have written one regex, but it looks lengthy. Can i apply some optimization logic for it?

`\A(?=[\w@=]{6,10}\z)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@=])`

on the other hand can i put logical AND type of concept in regex? please help

Comment: in which `language` you impliment

Comment: @Bhargav in javascript.

Comment: and how to optimize give some idea

Comment: share your code for better understanding

Comment: as you can see in the section `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@=])`, i am putting my condition individually, can i take commonality concept with logical and operation at here?

Comment: If there are 4 rules for your password string then there will be 4 separate lookaheads, there is no shortcut.

Comment: you manually create using local operator

Comment: @anubhava: no, 3 lookaheads, 1 match.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the principle of contrast and anchors:

```
(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])     # one UPPERCASE
(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])     # one lowercase
(?=\D*\d)            # one digit
(?=[^!"§$%]*[!"§$%]) # one symbol
^.{6,10}$            # 6-10 characters
```

As you can see it follows the rule

```
(?=[not this]{zero or more times}[this]{once})
```

and is likely faster than `.*` a couple of times.
But for n requirements, you'll need n-1 lookaheads and one matching mechanism.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/bXZAzX/1).